# React-redux with Flow - action type name from imported constant

Tags: javascript, react-redux, flowtype

I'm using Flow for type checking in React app using Redux, and need to check actions shape in reducers, depending on action type, as described here: https://flow.org/en/docs/react/redux/

reducer code:

```
import { ADD_USER, DELETE_USER } from './actionTypes'

type State = {
  users: { [userId: number]: { name: string, age: number } }
};  // exact State shape is not important for this case

type Action = 
  |{ type: ADD_USER, user: {name: string, age: number} }
  |{ type: DELETE_USER, userId: number };

function reducer(state: State, action: Action): State {
  switch(action.type) {
    case ADD_USER:
      return { ...state, users: { ...state.users, action.user } };

    case DELETE_USER:
      const { action.userId, ...newUsers } = state.users
      return { ...state, users: newUsers };

    default:
      return state;
  }
```

And that doesn't work, giving Flow error `Cannot get 'action.userId' because property 'userId' is missing in object type`.

When I define action types as constants in the same file, type checking works:

```
// import { ADD_USER, DELETE_USER } from './actionTypes'

const ADD_USER = 'ADD_USER';
const DELETE_USER = 'DELETE_USER';

type State = {
  users: { [userId: number]: { name: string, age: number } }
};  // exact State shape is not important for this case

type Action = 
  |{ type: ADD_USER, user: {name: string, age: number} }
  |{ type: DELETE_USER, userId: number };

function reducer(state: State, action: Action): State {
  switch(action.type) {
    case ADD_USER:
      return { ...state, users: { ...state.users, action.user } };

    case DELETE_USER:
      const { action.userId, ...newUsers } = state.users
      return { ...state, users: newUsers };

    default:
      return state;
  }
```

Importing action type names as string constants is needed because they are imported in action creators as well, so that keeps them all defined in one file `actionTypes.js` (sort of standard approach with react-redux).

How can Flow type checking with Disjoint Unions be performed with imported constants?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a few things needed to be done.

1) Add types to actions types in `actionTypes.js`. Make sure, that action types are assigned there as follows:

```
const ADD_USER: 'ADD_USER' = 'ADD_USER';
const DELETE_USER: 'DELETE_USER' = 'DELETE_USER';
```

2) In the annotation to Action type in reducer code, make sure that types and not values of action types are used, as follows:

```
import { ADD_USER, DELETE_USER } from './actionTypes'

type Action = 
  |{ type: typeof ADD_USER, user: {name: string, age: number} }
  |{ type: typeof DELETE_USER, userId: number };
```

3) Make sure, that all other code is valid JavaScript, as  `users: { ...state.users, action.user }` and `{ action.userId, ...newUsers } = state.users` do not look like legit way to do destructuring and creation of new object.

Comment: Thank you @frontendgirl, that notation: `const ADD_USER: 'ADD_USER' = 'ADD_USER';` did the trick!